# How to add normal map to material in Qt 3D?

Tags: qt, qt3d

I'm trying go apply normal map to `QDiffuseSpecularMaterial` or `QMetalRoughMaterial`. I Use `QTextureImage` to load the textures. When I try to apply `normal` material just becomes black, however, I don't have any issues with other maps (`baseColor`, `ambientOcclusion`, `metalness` and `roughness`)

What I've tried without success:

- Changed direction of vertex normals, but vertex normals are correct
- Swapped RGB channels in normal map texture - all the combinations. Also tried with grayscale texture
- Mapped values in texture loaded in `QPaintedTextureImage` from `(0, 255)` to `(0, 1)` range
- Thought that normal maps maybe don't work with `QPointLight`, so I've also added `QDirectionalLight` to the scene

Comment: Have you tried [`QNormalDiffuseSpecularMapMaterial`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt3dextras-qnormaldiffusespecularmapmaterial.html) already? I don't really get what the differences are but I guess it's worth a try.

Comment: Yes, I've tried it but still without visible result. Now I think that maybe the problem is that I don't have shadow maps implemented in the scene. There is a high chance I have to implement shadows before I can see the result

Comment: Something else you can try is to load your object using `QSceneLoader` and then check out the produced structure.

Comment: That is pretty good idea for debugging all qt3d code. Thanks